# How to visualise generic geometry column from SpatiaLite database in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I have a SpatiaLite database with various tables. One is a table called `Geometries` that has a `geometry` column which is defined as a generic Geometry column - that is, not POINT or POLYGON or anything, but just GEOMETRY and able to hold any sort of Geometry.

This seems to work fine in SpatiaLite, and when I view the data with `ogrinfo`, I get the right WKT printed out to the console.

However, when I try and view it in QGIS, I just get an entry in the layers list, but with nothing displayed in the main map canvas. I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem online.

Does QGIS support displaying tables with generic geometry columns? If not, is there a way to extract just the points and view them as a separate layer, and then just the polygons, and so on? Is there any other way around this?

Example images to show what I'm talking about are below:

Here's the list of tables in QGIS. It correctly identifies the geometry as GEOMETRY:
[image: Tables list]

But when I add it to the layers list, it appears with a strange icon, and nothing appears on the canvas:

[image: Layers list]

Comment: Can you show at least one element from this GEOMETRY table?

Comment: Where are you getting that list of tables from?

Comment: If I make a SpatiaLite DB file with mixed geometries I see this if I try and load via the "SpatialLite" entry in the "Browser", and loading layers from there fails the same way as you, but if I use "Layer... Add Layer... Add Vector Layer..." and find it as a file I get the point and polygon geometries split out into separate layers...

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman: adding the database through the Add Vector Layer and using it as a file works fine. I wonder why it doesn't work the same the other way - I imagine most people would expect to use Layer...Add Layer...Add SpatiaLite Layer option. Do you think I should report this issue somewhere?

Comment: yes, check the qgis bug tracker for prior reports. I'd file it as "Spatialite Browser shows mixed geometry tables as non-spatial" and note they read okay from "Add Vector Layer". The "strange icon" is QGIS saying "This is a non-spatial table" - you can load those in as layers and join spatial data to them by attribute for mapping.

Comment: The GeoPackage connection in the Browser works fine, showing two layers for my mixed geometry file. I'd recommend migrating to GeoPackage if at all possible!